# Redirect 301 url with question mark using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this site:

www.exampale.com/index.php?action=gallery&tag_id=X

**X is a number between 0 to 50,000.**

And I want to make a 301 redircet with htaccess to this site:

www.exampale.com/gallery/?tags=X

The same thing in this site:

www.exampale.com/?action=gallery&img_id=X **(Without index.php)**

To site:

www.exampale.com/image/view/X

I try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php?action=gallery&tag_id=([0-9]+)$ /gallery/?tags=$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^?action=gallery&img_id=([0-9]+)$ /image/view/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

But it wasn't works, and when I try it without "?" the code working good.

Somebody can help me? what is the code that I have to write in the htaccess file?

Thanks for help :-)

Comment: Redirect URL with Query strings https://helponnet.com/2019/06/21/how-to-redirect-a-url-with-query-string-apache-htaccess/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QueryString the url part after **?** is not part of match in RewriteRule's pattern. You need to match againg **%{QUERY_STRING}** variable using a **RewriteCond**

```
RewriteEngine on

#index.php?action=gallery&tag_id=123 =>/gallery/?tags=123
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=gallery&tag_id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/gallery/?tags=%1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Thank You! it's working, but when I try this on the another size it's make a problem. This is what I writing:

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=gallery&img_id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /image/view/%1 [NC,L,R]

Comment: change **/image/view/%1** to **/image/view/%1?** , notice the **?** char. This is important to remove old querystring from new url.